# App Maker Export Database Table in an Email HTML Format

Tags: google-app-maker

I have been searching all over the internet for a way to export a database table in google app maker by email in HTML format. Ideally, I'm looking for a simple solution like a button that you can click and confirm. It doesn't have to be good looking just has to work.

- Note this will be utilized on an inventory table.

Best,
Grant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to format the HTML table yourself and then use the `MailApp.sendEmail()` function using the `htmlBody` parameter.

It is possible to write some generic function which accepts an array of records and a header array (or a model object) and generates a HTML table.  I have not written such a function but below is a quick and dirty example for generating an HTML table and sending through email.

You would ideally have some event attached to an export button which passes `widget.datasource.items` to that HTML formatting function.

```js
// Array of records to send
var records = [
  {name:'Foo', owner:'Bob', date: new Date()}, 
  {name:'Bar', owner:'Max', date: new Date()}
]; 

// Instantiate table string
var table = '<table cellspacing="0" border="1" cellpadding="15" width="400">';

// Add header
table += '<tr><th>Name</th><th>Owner</th><th>Date</th>';

for(var i in records){
  var record = records[i];
  table += '<tr><td>' + record.name + '</td><td>' + 
           record.owner + '</td><td>' + 
           record.date.toLocaleString() + '</td></tr>';
}

table += '</table>';

// Send via MailApp service
var message = {
  to: 'me@gmail.com', 
  subject: 'Your HTML Table', 
  htmlBody: table, 
  body: 'Sorry, your mail client does not support HTML emails.'
};
MailApp.sendEmail(message);
```

And the output:

[image: Some sample output]

As an aside, if you have pagination enabled on your datasource your function will only include that many records.  Either disable pagination or load the records server side using `var records = app.models.myModel.newQuery().run()`.  You can also filter the returned records by way of normal query filters.